# Url.Content concept implementation in css mvc4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an application in mvc4. In one scenario of writting css, I have to use images as normal.

The problem I am facing is the more nested I did for css, the more "../" have to be used because I have kept images in Images folder on the application root and css in Content/themes/base/project.webiste folder.

So, here goes my css.

```
.contact-form h1.contact-header
{ 
background:url(../../../../Images/contactform-head.png) no-repeat top left; width:113px;
}
```

I was trying to do find some semantic solution. I mean, instead of counting "../" something meaningful like:

.contact-form h1.contact-header
    { 
    background:url(~/Images/contactform-head.png) no-repeat top left; width:113px;
    }

OR

.contact-form h1.contact-header
    { 
    background:@Url.Content(Images/contactform-head.png) no-repeat top left; width:113px;
    }

I even went through some other stackoverflow solutions and did goggling but without any success for addressing my issue. Most of them were about creating htmlhelper to address Url.Content for images. That solves the issue for .cshtml files or other but not .css.
I would be very much thankful if someone could come up with the solution I am looking for and also thanks to all others for their time.

Comment: Html helpers will not work in a .css file.  CSS files are not processed by the server and thus, will not render what you want.  Take a look at the posted answer and this website: http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would use a path relative to the project root. This way it doesn't matter where in the hierarchy your document is. 
For example:

```
.contact-form h1.contact-header
{ 
  background:url('/images/contactform-head.png') no-repeat top left;
}
```

The way it's written above means that in the website root folder there is a folder called `images` and inside of it there is a file called `contactform-head.png`. It doesn't matter where you reference this from (as long as it's on the same domain). It will work just fine.